# Syntax error near unexpected token "done"-- while read line

Tags: bash, shell-script, readline

I keep getting this error: `syntax error near unexpected token 'done'` but I don't understand why.

I tried adding `dos2unix *.sh` after `#!/bin/sh`, but that just gave me an error that said no such file or directory in addition to the "done" error.

This is a .sh file. I'm very new to writing scripts. Help?

I'm running

sh thisfile.sh program_input input

on linux

**edit** I added some quotations around the variables- same error

```
#!/bin/sh
fst=$1
input=$2
while read line
do
    result=$(cat "$line" | program "$fst")
    if [ "$result" = "" ];
    then
        printf "$line\t=>\t *none* 0\n"
    else
        printf "$line\t=>\tyes\n"
    fi
done < "$input"
```

"$input" is just four rows of words like
"they" "can" "fish"
"they" "can" "take" "table"

If I run `cat "$line" | program "$fst"` it works fine

**note** if I take out everything in the loop and just printf $line it gives the same "done" syntax error

Comment: Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: What text editor do you use?

Comment: As a side note, `echo -e` is not POSIX.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you are doing any redirection with that `echo` with the backticks argument.

Comment: I just added the backticks so that I could put the variables in quotations everywhere they are used, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: It would be useful to add the exact command you executed (you tag bash, you have different shebang, you didn't add the arguments) and the file you used for input.

Comment: I just added more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`syntax error near unexpected token 'done'` is the error Bash gives when it sees the reserved word `done` without a matching `do` before it. It has nothing to do with quotes, but most likely a lot to do with your file having DOS/Windows-style CRLF line endings. The carriage return (CR, `\r`) is seen by the shell as a regular character, so it doesn't see the reserved word `do`, but `do\r` instead. On the other hand, on the last line it does recognize `done`, since it's separated from the line end, and the CR there with that space.

Run the script file itself through `dos2unix`. Don't add the `dos2unix` command *in* the script file.

Comment: This was the issue. I was trying to run it in the script file and just getting errors, but running the file through dos2unix fixed everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
#!/bin/sh
program_input="$1"
input="$2"
cat "$input" | while read line
do
    result=$(echo "$line" | program -sli "$program_input")
    if [ "$result" = "" ] 
    then
        printf "$line\t=>\t *none* 0\n"
    else
        printf "$line\t=>\tyes\n"
    fi
done
```

- `result=$( ... )` is prefered over result=`...` (backquote)

the command

```
echo -e `"$line"\t=>\tyes`
```

means :

- execute `"$line"\t=>\tyes`
- redirecting output from `"$line" =` to `yes`
- and `echo -e whatever result` (result should be empty, either stdout caught in yes or stderr uncaught).

Is that what you want ?

purist might object about useless use of cat as

```
cat "$input" | while read file
do

done
```

can be replace by

```
while read file
do

done < "$input"
```

however if while loop is too many line, it might not be easy to guess what while is reading.

Comment: I will edit my question with my changes and the input files- I am still getting the same error with these changes.

Comment: This didn't answer my question, but you did help me format and understand my code better, so thank you!